# need help to figure out what is the error, it's jQuery code

Tags: jquery, lightbox

i'm trying to make something like light box for a message with jQuery and CSS
but it doesn't work!!!
here is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    function myFunction(){
        $("#overLay").hide();
        $("#x").hide();
        $("#message").hide();
    }

    $("#overLay").click( myFunction() );
    $("#x").click( myFunction() );

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "It doesn't work" is meaningless to everyone but you. In what way does it "not work"? What does "not work" mean? When you're asking questions, please remember we can't read your mind (or code) from where we are - if you don't provide the info, we can't know it. Also, you might read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for tips on how to ask better questions in order to improve your chances of getting an answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction(){
    $("#overLay").hide();
    $("#x").hide();
    $("#message").hide();
}
$(function(){ //run after page is loaded
   $("#overLay").click(myFunction);
   $("#x").click(myFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(){
 $("#overLay").hide();
 $("#x").hide();
 $("#message").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#overLay").click( function(){
  myFunction(); 
 });
 $("#x").click( function(){
  myFunction();
 } );
});
```

Comment: Build an anonymous function just to call another function?  Overkill :P

Answer (score 0):

*As for the syntactical part,* The way you are calling the functions are wrong, call them without the parenthesis

```
$("#overLay").click( myFunction );
$("#x").click( myFunction );
```